# Connect to a docker process from host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

On a docker container setup (3 containers) using user-defined bridge network.

- I am able to reach a container from another container (using both IP and container name).
- But I am not able to ping the process (running in container) from my host machine. Can any one help me in this? is it possible?

See my [docker compose file](https://github.com/user-rohitsh/docker-setups/blob/master/kafka/servers.yml)

Set up is on windows 8

Of the 4 containers mentioned in the compose file - none is accessible from host machine. (neither using container names nor IP ). Although I can access one container from another one using both IP and container name.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a [mcve]; in particular, edit your question to include a subset of your `docker-compose.yml` that demonstrates the issue (don't just include a link) and explain which container is actually unreachable and how you're trying to reach it.

Comment: Are you using 'Docker For WIndows' or 'Docker Toolbox'?

Comment: I am using Docker Toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to access your container from its service name declared in the compose file, but you cannot do that outside the `bridge` network declared in the compose file.

From your host, you need to use the container ip address and you can get it with the following command:

```
docker inspect <container> -f '{{.NetworkSettings.Networks.<network>.IPAddress}}'
```

Obviously you need to replace the `<container>` placeholder by your container name and the `<network>` by you network name.

For example, based on you `servers.yml` file, you can get the `zookeeper` ip address with `docker inspect zookeeper -f '{{.NetworkSettings.Networks.bridge.IPAddress}}'`

See the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) for more details on the `inspect` command and

Comment: I tried the same too. But its not accessible using IP also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much more idea about Docker setup on windows but I guess your service is listening on `localhost`(inside the container) that's why it is not accessible from outside

To access any of the service running on the container from outside you need to bind the service port with `0.0.0.0` IP address

**Example:**

If Nginx is running on port 80 inside the container but the bind    address is `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`(It will be accessible only from    inside the container not outside or from host machine), If you want to access your nginx from outside you need to change its    bind address `localhost` to `0.0.0.0`

Hope it will help.